# In Drupal 7 Commerce, how do you change the "View Cart" link in the cart block to something else?

Tags: 7, blocks, commerce

In the Cart Block in drupal 7 commerce. How do you change the "View Cart" link. I want to change it to Edit Cart instead.

http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2502/8yfy.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways.

You could implement the Commerce hook to adjust the line item summary info

[hook_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info_alter](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info_alter/7)

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info_alter
 */
function MY_MODULE_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info_alter(&$links) {
  if (!empty($links['view_cart'])) {
    $links['view_cart']['title'] = t('View the magical cart');
  }
}
```

See also [commerce_cart_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!cart!commerce_cart.module/function/commerce_cart_commerce_line_item_summary_link_info/DC) for the default data.

Another way, as mentioned by 4life, is with the [stringoverrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module or if you aren't using it already, you can change the text in *settings.php* without an additional module

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'View cart' => 'View the magical cart',
);
```

Either of those approaches should work there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [string override module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides).

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

Comment: thanks, but i was wondering if there was a setting within commerce that can override such a string. if there isn't, then yes I would have to use string override module.